# PYTHON: How to return a dictionary key if a list contains all values for that key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Using python.

Trying to make a recipe program that tells me what meals(key) I can make based off of the current ingredients(list) that I have.

Here is my meal dictionary, the key is the meal and the value is the required ingredients:

```
breakfast = {
    "cerealBowl" : ["milk", "cereal"],
    "toast" : ["bread", "butter"],
    "eggsBacon" : ["eggs", "bacon"],
    "frenchToast" : ["bread", "eggs"]
}
```

And here is my list of ingredients that I currently have:

```
currentIngredients = ["milk", "bread", "rice", "butter", "eggs"]
```

I would like the program to return the meals(key) that I can make if all of the values are in my current ingredients list.

So far I have:

```
def scanRecipes():
    for item in currentIngredients:
```

I'm not sure how to setup my next for loop/if statement to itterate over my breakfast dictionary values and compare the ingredients to my currentIngredients list.

Looking to get an output similar to:

```
"Meals available to make..." "toast" with ["bread", "butter"],"frenchToast" with ["bread", "eggs"]
```

Comment: Make the ingredients a set.  Sets have `issubset` and `issuperset` mtehods that will do this in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over your recipes dict and filter to the recipes where you have all the ingredients:

```
breakfast_recipes = {
    "cerealBowl" : ["milk", "cereal"],
    "toast" : ["bread", "butter"],
    "eggsBacon" : ["eggs", "bacon"],
    "frenchToast" : ["bread", "eggs"]
}

def get_recipes(ingredients):
    return {
        r: i for r, i in breakfast_recipes.items()
        if set(ingredients).issuperset(set(i))
    }

current_ingredients = ["milk", "bread", "rice", "butter", "eggs"]
print("Meals available to make...")
for r, i in get_recipes(current_ingredients).items():
    print(f"{r} with {i}")
```

```
Meals available to make...
toast with ['bread', 'butter']
frenchToast with ['bread', 'eggs']
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain "r: i for r, i in breakfast_recipes.items()", never done something like that and I'm a bit confused by it

Comment: It's a dictionary comprehension, similar to a list comprehension, but specifying both a key and a value.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

```
currentIngredients = set(["milk", "bread", "rice", "butter", "eggs"])
for key,ing in breakfast.items():
    if currentIngredients.issuperset(set(ing)):
        print( "You can make", key )
```

Answer (score 0):

### Available meals

You may for each meal in `breakfast` look if the each required ingredient is in your `currentIngredients` list:

```
available_meals = []
for meal, ingredients in breakfast.items():
    available_ingrs = 0
    for ingr in ingredients:
        if ingr in currentIngredients:
            available_ingrs += 1
    if available_ingrs == len(ingredients): #if all required ingredients were met
        available_meals.append((meal, ingredients))
```

Other answers are more elegant as they use the `issuperset` method.
A is said to be a superset of B if A contains all elements of B.
In this case, `currentIngredients` may be a superset of `ingredients` if `currentIngredients` contains all the elements of `ingredients`:

```
set(currentIngredients).issuperset(ingredients) #returns a boolean
```

*Note that the `issuperset` function is a method of the `set` type. That's why you have to convert `currentIngredients` to a `set`.*

### Printing an output

A simple printing program which iterates the `available_meals` list:

```
def printMeals():
    print("Meals available to make...")
    for elem in available_meals:
        print(repr(elem[0]), "with", elem[1])
```